# How to make page scroll to certain class depending on day of the week?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a WP page to scroll to certain class according to day of the week. On each day I want the users browsers to scroll to the current day and on Sunday to go to Monday.

HTML added to a WordPress page

```
<h2>Activities</h2>
<ul>
   <li><span class="monday">Monday</span>xyz</li>  
   <li><span class="tuesday">Tuesday</span>xyz</li>
   <li><span class="wednesday">Wednesday</span>xyz</li>
   <li><span class="thursday">Thursday</span>xyz</li>
   <li><span class="friday">Friday</span>xyz</li>
   <li><span class="saturday">Saturday</span>xyz</li>    
</ul>
```

I know I need the getDay JS to determine the current day, but I have a hard time getting the page to scroll. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
vik3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/rephuby3/

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".wednesday").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

See this link for more help on the subject:
[jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

**Update:**

To scroll on load see: 
https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/rephuby3/1/

To scroll based on weekday name:
https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/rephuby3/3/

Comment: Thanks, it's a great pointer, but I need the scrolling to be automated, according to day of the week.

Comment: @vik3d Automated as in onPageLoad?

Comment: @vik3d See my updated answer, I show both how to scroll on page load, and how to scroll on page load with weekday name.

Comment: Wow! I'm grateful for your help! Thank you!